# Adding new fonts to Pdf invoice Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, pdf, fonts

When working with Pdf invoice, I meet **a problem about encoding Japanese font. I'm going to add a Japanese font(Gothic) to Pdf invoice, creditmemo, etc. What should I do?**

We may rewrite abstract `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` class? Because there are some "hard code" functions to set fonts for Pdf.

```
 protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
 {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/fonts/Gothic.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
 }
  ......

 protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
 {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/fonts/Gothic.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
 }
```

There are some similar issues [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2766) and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1145).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code it seems like the font can be set dynamically, see this code from the `drawLineBlocks` method:

```
$font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($column['font_file']);
$page->setFont($font, $fontSize);
```

The `$column['font_file']` comes from the `$draw` array given in the method parameters.

So what you could try is to declare a plugin on this method

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf">
        <plugin name="add_font_to_pdf" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddFontToPdf" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddFontToPdf.php` you can do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class AddFontToPdf
{
    public function beforeDrawLineBlocks($subject, $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = [])
    {
        $newDraw = $draw;
        // Update the $draw array to add your font
        return [$page, $newDraw, $pageSettings];
    }

}
```

NB: you will need to replace the comment with the code that will let you add the font to the draw array yourself obviously.

Comment: Which font is best suitable for PDFs?

Comment: i have did it but not working for me.